# Watir-Webdriver not picking data from form

Tags: automation, watir-webdriver

I'm automating few forms using watir-webdriver (0.6.4). I have observed few times even though the data is entered, the browser still throws popup saying insert mandatory fields.

I have tried options like set, value='' but still the problem persists.

Any idea how to make this form filling 100% robust?

Thanks in advance,
VJ

Comment: It would help if you give an example of form field (ex is it a Dijit control, jQuery control, etc). My guess (based on my experience with a similar problem) is that your form field needs to populate some other hidden field. The events to populate that hidden field are not being triggered by Watir, which is why the validation fails.

Comment: Hi Justin, the form fields are Dijit control. Most of the time, same code runs successfully, but sometimes it throws popup saying enter mandatory fields, even though the data is entered in the fields.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on the sample [Dijit controls](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/)? It would help us give an useful answer (rather than randomly guessing what might work).